# CSV new-line character and qoute inside quoted field

Tags: python, csv

I have tried so many options inside csv.reader but its not working. I am new to python and tried almost every parameter,the single messy message inside my csv file look like this

```
"Hey Hi

how are you all,I stuck into this problem,i have tried with such parameter but exceeding the existing number of records,in short file is not getting read properly.
\"I have tried with 
datareader=csv.reader(csvfile,quotechar='"',lineterminator='\n\n\n\r\r',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode? \"......... hence the problem continue.

"
```

as expected due to **\"** and **\n** in message getting more records or the records getting break,i have tried with different line terminator as well as you can see in the message but not succeed,this is my code right now..

```
with open("D:/Python/mssg5.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile,quotechar='"' ,lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        count = 0
    #csv_out = open('D:/Python/mycsv.csv', 'wb')
    #mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
        for row in datareader:
            count = count + 1
            print "COUNT is :%d" % count
```

Any kind of help,thanks.

Comment: It's hard te replicate your problem, could you provide a csv-file and give us some details abouts the file-encoding etc? Btw, did you simply try using the universal newline mode ("rU" instead of "r") ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try **in the csv file**:

1. Put the messy string into tipple quotes """  the string """
2. At the end of each line within your messy field use the continue char \